# Datagridview AutoSizeColumnsMode not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, resolution, autosize

**Users**
So I have different users that are using different resolutions due to eyesight / preferences, whatever.

**Form**
One of the C# forms that comes up has a datagridview with **AutoSizeColumnsMode** set to **Fill**. I realize from the reading of the object in MSDN that with **Fill** you cannot use the left-right scroll bar.

**Problem**
So the problem is when the datagridview loads. The columns look great on the high resolution and fill the datagridview all the way to its borders as it should. On the lower resolution screen, some columns are hidden and must be stretched by the user to view, since the scroll bar is not enabled with the **Fill** option.

**Attempts**
I tried **DisplayedCells** option which does give the user the scroll bar on the lower resolution and it looks / works great. But on the higher resolution, it leaves large gaps between the last column and the border of the Datagridview and looks unfinished / broken.

**Question**
How can I say "Set to Fill unless the user is using really low resolution, then use **DisplayedCells**?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the resolution by

```
        int screenWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int screenHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

And then use an if-clause to set AutoSizeColumnsMode-Property.

Like this:

```
    private void getScreenResolution()
    {
        int screenWidth = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        int screenHeight = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    }

    private void setAutoSizeColumnsMode()
    {
        if (screenWidth <= 1680 || screenHeight  <= 768)
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        else
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    }
```

Comment: That was too easy... thanks. Not sure how to give you the answer vote, it won't let me due to low rep, sorry. 
SK

Comment: I meant not sure how to give you the vote, I did give you the answer obviously =)